# hard drive partisions not displayed during installation

Tags: release-odin, install

After boot live media, i selected custom installation to select partitions but after one or two minutes, installation setup could not find or display or detect my partitions.
i ran Gparted during partition selection step and it could detect and show my HDD and partitions.

why elementary os 6 not display my drive/partitions to continue installation?

I have not any issue with ubuntu or mint or even elementary os 5.1.

Comment: What is the brand and model of your computer? Some computers need a couple of BIOS settings changed to properly show their storage devices ... and some won't easily show them at all 

Comment: toshiba HDD, i have not any issue with mint or ubuntu.